# Find Austrian vital records?

Tags: birth-records, jewish, austria

My grandfather was born 1931 in [Deutchkreutz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschkreutz) Austria.
Are there any websites I could find any records of his (especially birth record)? I tried to look up his name in [Ancestry](http://ancestry.com) with no luck.

Are there [JRI-Poland](http://jri-poland.org)-like websites dedicated for Austria?

Comment: You are unlikely to find a 1931 birth record online. (European privacy laws often restricts access, as well)  The best place to start would be to narrow down where in Austria he was born.

Comment: He was born in a town called [Deutchkreutz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschkreutz), and besides any other documents except birth will also be very helpful, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://www.jewishgen.org/AustriaCzech/ausguide.htm, easily findable via Google.

Comment: I wandered around in that website, but couldn't find an accessible database searchable online. I've already searched JewishGen which yielded no results.

Comment: JewishGen has many different "SIG"'s (Special Interest Groups) for different areas.  Each one has its own dedicated e-mail listserve.  I would join the one for the Austria-Czech group, as listed above.  If you're on Facebook, you could also message Randy (E. Randol) Schoenberg for advice; he's the head of that group.  They may know about resources that are not online, or which are shared privately.

Answer (score 3):

You will find the birth records in the registers of the confessional institution since he was born before 1938 (the registration authorities started their work in 1938 in Austria afaik, see e.g. for Vienna here, but unfortunately German only: http://www.wien.gv.at/kultur/archiv/nutzung/forschung/personen.html)

In case he was roman catholic, you can contact the parish Deutschkreutz via mail: http://www.martinus.at/adressbuch/pfarre/27621042008143457.html or kreuzkirche@pfarredeutschkreutz.at

Ususally they will email you the requested documents.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  I hope you will find your participation here rewarding.

Comment: Hi Alex, and thanks for the resources, fortunately I speak Yiddish, so I pretty much get along with German. As the question is marked Jewish, he was not catholic, but best thing leave the reference in your answer for future reference for other users.

Comment: Hi Shimmy, sorry - I overlooked the tag... In that case, I'd contact the Israelitische Kultusgemeinde in Vienna and ask them how to best proceed on this. Contact information can be found here: [http://www.ikg-wien.at/?page_id=625&lang=en]

Answer (score 2):

The website to check is http://genteam.at, which has millions of records from Austria on its site. The problem is that European privacy laws prevent access to records as recent as 1931. However, there are people on the mailing list who may have access beyond what is available to you, and it might be worth asking a question on their [mailing list](http://www.genlist.at/mailman/listinfo/austria).

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE! I've added a link to the page with the information about the mailing list.  If you know of a better entry point, please edit your answer and fix it.